# How to add a custom field with a link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box that contains a link and I would like when I click on that link the system opens the site I entered in the text box in form Acumatica.
How to do that? Any ideas?

I wrote a piece of javascript code to transform a text field into a link.
However, I cannot find a way to inject this code into the quote display screen (SO301000).

Comment: Please add some detail and code to your question. As it stands now it's very unclear

Comment: No, this question is very straightforward, you just need to know Acumatica to understand the context. However, the tags could be more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change PXTextEdit to PXLinkEdit in the ASPX file.

```
<px:PXLinkEdit ID="edDefContactWebSite" runat="server" DataField="WebSite" CommitChanges="True" ></px:PXLinkEdit>
```

It is not exactly what you need, but it is the standard Acumatica way.

Comment: How to accept it, please ?